# I've known Mr. Smith since 2001 when we

Tags: grammar

> I've known Mr. Smith since 2001, when we were studying together at the University of Harvard.

Is this sentence correct?

I want it to mean

> I got to know Mr. Smith in 2001, when we were studying together at the same university. Since then, this state has continued.

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning of that question

Comment: Note that you'd be unlikely to refer to someone who was a fellow student as "Mr".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Mr Smith is absent, then your sentence would imply that your relationship (of knowing Mr Smith) had continued. If the relationship had not continued I would say *I knew Mr. Smith in 2001, when we were studying together at the University of Harvard*.

On the other hand if Mr Smith is present and part of a conversation, for example if a third person introduced you to Mr Smith, your sentence would not necessarily mean that your relationship with him had continued unbroken, but might mean that the relationship was now being renewed.